# How do I completely disable my dedicated/discrete (AMD/ATI) graphic card in Xubuntu 18.04 & 20.04 live non-persistent USB?

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, xubuntu, amd-graphics

The graphic card is fried and I think that's what's causing the session to freeze every time after the computer warms up.

Things I've tried so far...

1. Adding `radeon.modeset=0` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in the file `/etc/default/grub` so that it reads:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"
   ```
2. Adding `radeon.modeset=0`in `cdrom/syslinux/txt.cfg` as well as `syslinux.cfg`
3. Logging in "safe graphics".

Obviously, non of the above worked.

Appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thanks loads in advance!

---

UNetbootin & Ventoy (I can use any other tool).

BIOS : Insydeh20 | Rev. 3.5 | F.29

Comment: Usually, this should be possible to do in your BIOS/EUFI settings

Comment: Not necessarily. My old Thinkpad has an intel cpu with an integrated card + an Nvidia GPU, but I've got no chance to switch it. Depends on your hardware and/or Bios. Question is, do you see that integrated card? If the above doesn't work, it looks like the integrated gpu is masked.  @JJrussel: If you add information about your hardware to your question it would help.

Comment: @BulleyBob no option to change in BIOS on my laptop

Comment: @kanehekili What information would you like?

Comment: CPU, exact type of Hardware (Laptop,PC ) and BIOS brand & version. We need to figure out, if we can reach your integrated GPU, if you've got one

Comment: @kanehekili Yes I do. `inxi -G` lists it

Comment: `inxi -CG` would give clues about the CPU as well. And `sudo dmidecode -t bios`. Use the **edit** link to paste the data into your question

Comment: @kanehekili edited

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116480/discussion-between-kanehekili-and-jjrussel).

Comment: If this is a laptop you probably can't disable it because your device has "hybrid graphics". These configurations do not use a truly dedicated GPU as they work in tandem with your CPU.  If you have a desktop computer, remove the card and plug your display into a port on the motherboard, assuming your CPU has a iGPU, otherwise you need to buy another GPU if this one is damaged.

Comment: @Nmath It's a laptops. In Windows I can disable it easily in just a couple of clicks through device manager. When I first boot into Windows the screen is green and grainy, and becomes normal as soon as I disable the ATI graphic card. Surely there is a way to accomplish the same thing in Linux. Compared to Windows, Linux seems to be lightyears ahead in difficultly and lack of user friendliness.

Comment: The implementation of hybrid graphics in laptops is not standardized and wildly inconsistent between devices, so I would approach your problem as a hardware-specific issue. Maybe you can find out how it actually works behind the scenes in Windows and that might give you some hint of the hardware implementation.  When you learn how to do things, they stop becoming difficult. Windows and Linux are very different from one another in form and function. Don't expect them to be the same or even to cater to the same audience. If you grew up on Windows of course it would more user friendly to you

Comment: Your problem is far from typical after all: you want your operating system to ignore broken, yet still connected hardware

Comment: @Nmath Yes. Windows does that. It cuts off the blood supply...like a paralyzed limb. And I was talking about the same device. If I log into Windows, I can just disable the graphic card. But when I log into Linux, "on the same device", I can't? That doesn't seem like a hardware limitation to me.

Comment: My apologies, I think you've misunderstood my advice. I suggested that there must be some under-the-hood process that is going on when you click to disable the GPU in Windows and that understanding that process might shed light on how you might do the same in Ubuntu. It's not a limb and blood thing, obviously, but maybe if there is some Windows documentation, either from MS or from the hardware manufacturer, it could be helpful to understand how exactly it's disabled.  Just a suggestion, since I don't know the answer either